# How to add required to sub array in a json schema?

Tags: arrays, json, schema, jsonschema, required

I'm creating a json schema to define necessary data with data types. There is some data need to be set into `required` filed. But didn't find how to do it in its document.

For this json schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "version",
    "categories"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "version": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 1
    },
    "categories": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "body": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

json like

```
{
   "version":"1",
   "categories":[
      {
         "title":"First",
         "body":"Good"
      },
      {
         "title":"Second",
         "body":"Bad"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to set `title` to be required, too. It's in a sub array. How to set it in json schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your schema. I'm going to assume you're using JSON Schema draft 2019-09.

First, you want `items` to be an object, not an array, as you want it to apply to every item in the array.

> If "items" is a schema, validation succeeds if all elements in the
> array successfully validate against that schema.
>
> If "items" is an array of schemas, validation succeeds if each
> element of the instance validates against the schema at the same
> position, if any.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-02#section-9.3.1.1

Second, if the value of `items` should be a schema, you need to treat it like a schema in its own right.

If we take the item from your `items` array as a schema, it doesn't actually do anything, and you need to nest it in a `properties` keyword...

```
{
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "body": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, now your `items` keyword value is a schema (subschema), you can add any keywords you can normally use, such as `required`, the same as you have done previously.

```
{
  "required": [
    "title"
  ],
  "properties": {
    ...
  }
}
```